# Ошибка TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Tags: python

Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так:

```
from models import User

def get_user_by_id(user_id):
    try:
        return User().get(vk_id=user_id)
    except:
        User(
            vk_id=user_id,
            warns=0
        ).save()
        return User().get(vk_id=user_id)
```

> IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: Не так: разные сообщения об ошибках в заголовке и в тексте. Кстати, сообщения об ошибках пишутся для того, чтобы их читать. И в них коротко и ясно написано, что именно не так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Для `try` вы использовали **табулятор**,
- но для `except` **4 пробела**.

Так невозможно: или табуляторы, или пробелы.

(Или *та же самая последовательность табуляторов и пробелов* перед `try` и перед `except`.)

Comment: спасибо огромное!